# Difference between creation of DOM elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, dom

I'm wondering if there is a difference in performance (or what is the best practice) in creating DOM elements with jQuery.

By my knowlegde there are 3 ways to do this:

1. By string:

   ```
   $('<a href="http://www.example.com" class="footerLink" rel="external">example</a>');`
   ```
2. Create element first, add attributes later:

   ```
   $('<a></a>')
     .addClass('footerLink')
     .attr({ 
        rel: 'external, 
        href: 'http://www.example.com' 
     })
     .text('example');
   ```
3. Create element and pass attributes object with it:

   ```
   $('<a></a>', {
     'class': 'footerLink', 
     href: 'http://www.example.com',
     rel: 'external'
   })
   .text('example');
   ```

**EDIT:**
What if you are appending a lot of items to an element? Should you make a very long `string` first and append that after the loop?

Comment: You're missing `.text("example")` in 2 and 3. That asidem why don't you visit http://jsperf.com/, and see it yourself?

Comment: Check this: http://jsperf.com/jquery-add-element - Looks like the fastest way is the first one..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way for you to be to create the entire DOM you want to attach as string and then attach it to the document as `html()`:

```
var dom = '<a href="http://www.example.com" class="footerLink" rel="external">example</a>';
$(element).html(dom);
```

Of the three that you have in your example the fastest should be the 3rd one, for the reason that it does not have to do any complex string parsing and the attributes are not put using chained function calls but are provided as a single object as a parameter to the selector.

[There is a forum thread on jQuery you may want to check out.](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/inserting-dom-performance)

**Update:**

If you are creating a lot of items to an element, then you should definitely take the string approach. Take a look at the following example of making a 1000 list elements.

```
// Assume we have data defined with 1000 data members
// each containing a text property
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    list.push('<li>' + data.text + '</li>');
}
$(ul).html(list.join(''));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article! So DOM-element creation by passing a string to change the innerHtml has the best performance. However I don't like the markup, it makes the code less readable. What do you think?

Comment: @WillemdeWit Yes that would be correct. Less readable but better performing.

Comment: Maybe I should dive into a template plugin such as jQuery tmpl. Maybe I can have both, performance and nice markup.

Comment: @WillemdeWit Templating plugins actually greatly decrease performance of rendering. jQuery templating especially is poorly performing on large data sets. The tests that we have done show an average rendering time of 5.6 seconds for 10000 data records 4 properties in each.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Konstantin, the string approach is the better performance-wise. I would like to point out, however, that if the DOM string is not known at the time of writing the code (eg the text comes from user input), then the slower approach would make sense to :

- avoid long series of string concatenations
- give jquery's ["text"](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method a chance to sanitize the string before outputing

In the end, this might really be a job for a templating framework (mustache or others...)